# CDI using an interceptor for a decorator

Tags: decorator, cdi, interceptor

I would like to know if it is possible by definition, that a decorator may have an interceptor for a method or not. I am using owb and it does not work!

EDIT: Just tested it with WELD and it's the same! Why does a decorator may not have an interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO: Methods in the decorator are never called directly through a contextual reference, therefore must not interceptable.  These are container invocations of methods.